# Не могу задать Primary Key. Flask, SQLite, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Пытаюсь работать с SQLite, по гайду (youtube.com/watch?v=G-si1WbtNeM&t), всё работает, но не задаётся id (pk), пытаюсь разными способами, либо записывается None, либо говорит что SQLite не поддерживает аттрибут autoincrement=True, а как правильно - не понятно.

В интернетах ничего не нашёл, имеющаяся информация устарела, а для документации я видимо слишком глуп. Можете подсказать как правильно?

[image: Таблица базы данных]

Текст ошибки: "(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: video.id [SQL: INSERT INTO video (type, link, downloads, registered, last_request) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)] [parameters: (0, 'G-si1WbtNeM', 0, '2022-08-02 13:15:50.468703', '2022-08-02 13:15:50.468703')] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)"

Comment: Вот это читали https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html ? И я не понял, у вас там на картинке **два** праймари кея или я что-то не понимаю?? В остальном то всё выглядит правильно, единственно что `ASC` возможно нужно для этой колонки с ключом указать, а так всё должно само получиться, если колонка `INTEGER`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Действительно, я ступил и поставил два primary_key, запутался немного) Можно узнать что вы имели в виду под "единственно что ASC возможно нужно для этой колонки с ключом указать"?

Comment: Ну я не знаю как это через код делается и возможно по дефолту всё уже и так нормально. Просто если вы почитаете доку по ссылке, то для `DESC` сортировки поля автоинкремент не будет работать, если я правильно понял что там написано. В общем, если и так заработает, то не берите в голову.